# Insetting a line in a cube

Tags: grease-pencil

I am very new to Blender (and 3D modeling in general), and I'm trying to do something I consider fairly simple, but seems beyond my grasp.  I'm trying to make a base that looks like this:

[image]

I have two cubes, shaped and scaled properly, but I want to make the lines inset into the top portion of the base.  I've tried using a grease pencil and turning it into a curve, then a mesh, and using a boolean modifier, but my primary issue there is actually getting it 3D and not just a flat mark.  The second issue is getting it aligned properly so that I can use a copy of the same grease pencil (or whatever the appropriate tool is) around all four sides so that they are identical.

I've watched many YouTube videos and checked out questions areound here on SE, but can't seem to find an appropriate answer, probably because I don't know the words or tools that would lead me there.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the model in the picture is sculpted and not modelled in that sense.

Comment: Because of the profile of the cuts you can just create a Texture with the pattern and use a Displacement Modifier.

Comment: @rob ooooh, makes sense. I’ll give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: @HenrikD I agree, but that has nothing to do with me wanting to model it now. :)